# Maven Test is not running in quark-concourse pipeline

Tags: spring-boot, maven, maven-surefire-plugin, concourse-pipeline

The test cases are running locally fine but on concourse pipeline its shows no test is nunning.

`Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0`

These are the plugins used in application:

[image]

And on console of IntelliJ the following logs are shown:

```
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:testCompile (java-test-compile) @ cpp-common-sb-2 ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2:test (default-test) @ cpp-common-sb-2 ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  01:10 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-04-17T16:57:50+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

Process finished with exit code 0
```